# My lemon tree, ants, shells. What is this and how to treat it properly?

Tags: diagnosis, fruit-trees, pest-control, lemons, ants

There are lots of ants around, they just don't like to be photographed :)
[image: close up]

[image: another close up]

This is the whole tree:
[image: the whole tree]

I'm in Sydney, Australia.

Comment: Don't worry about the ants, they're only on the plant to collect honeydew from the scale infestation. Treat for scale and the ants will disappear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears to be [scale insects](http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/plant-problems/pests/insects/control-plant-scale.htm).

I'm not experienced with scales, but I imagine you can use neem oil and/or diatomaceous earth once in a while to help. I would get the diatomaceous earth all over the stems, wherever they are. I hear you can put a circle of cinnamon or something around your pot to help deter ants.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Looks to me like it's the case of **armoured scale** but not sure.

Comment: it is scale, the hard brown bumps on the stems and leaves

Comment: @Shule no need to link off site try this link http://gardening.stackexchange.com/search?q=scale